# Opening file geodatabase in python

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, cursor

I'm new to python and this is my script:

```
import arcpy,sys
input=sys.argv[1]
field=sys.argv[2]
try:
    cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input,field)
    getvalue=[row.getValue(field) for row in cursor]
    values=set(getvalue)
    print values
    del cursor
except:
    del cursor
```

When its trying to run cursor, the following error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erfan\Desktop\Script2.py", line 6, in <module>
    cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input,field)
RuntimeError: cannot open 'D:\gis\data\network'
```

By the way, I want to access a feature class inside a feature dataset in gdb.

Comment: 'D:\gis\data\network' isn't a path to a feature class within a feature dataset within a gdb

Comment: The `row.getValue()` method applies to the old `arcpy` cursors, not to the (not so) new `arcpy.da` cursors.

Answer (score 5):

Your argument 1 path should be something like this to reference a gdb feature dataset feature class (as a python string):

```
'D:/gis/data/network/test.gdb/myFeatureDataset/myFC' # also back slashes will error out interpreted as line returns by python, use forward slashes instead
```

And as @GISGe commented, getValue() method is for the older cursor type, use `row[0]` instead (for first field in field variable list or `row[1]` for second field in field variable list).  See examples here, [Search Cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm).